# Margin elements without affeting other elements

Tags: margin

I have an Eelementor section with 9 columns. I want to put the first and last column on the border and I did this by giving a negative margin to the first and last columns but after doing this, my whole section columns moved and the section went into a mess. What should I do?

I want to put the first and last column on the border with an equal distance between all columns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl1oz.jpg)

Comment: Please include a [mre] of the problem, debugging without seeing the code is generally impossible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.